# shopify : I need to change description when select any of the color, Description should display according to my selection

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shopify

I want to display the relevant description when I select the colour but I don't know where I did the mistake in this code. Help me And Thanks For Your Support.

Description HMTL Code is

```
<p class="description" id="12357376442470">SKU A Detail </p>
<p class="description" id="12361855139942" style="display: none;">SKU B Detail</p>
```

And product.liquid code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {

   // Simply toggle on/off the panel according to the variant selected
$('.description').css('display', 'none');
$('#' + variant.id).css('display', 'block');
 // rest of the Timber code
}
</script>
```

[image: Grey image with varient ID but description still same]

[image: Black image with varient ID but description syill same]

Comment: Are there errors in the browser console? Can you add a link to your web page that isn't working?

Comment: https://motoca.myshopify.com/products/rizoma-leggera-l-led-turn-signal-running-light?variant=12361855139942